# PHP function bbcode make optional to replace smileys

Tags: php

I want to give the oppurtunity to the user if he wants his smileys to be replaced with image smileys.

I tried this.

`bbcode($text, TRUE);`

```
function bbcode($str, $smileys = false)
{
    $str = htmlentities($str);

$find = array(

if ($smileys == true) {
 ':p',
}

    '/\[b](.*?)\[\/b]/i',
    '/\[u](.*?)\[\/u]/i',
 '/\[i](.*?)\[\/i]/i',
 '/\[img](.*?)\[\/img]/i',
 '/\[url](.*?)\[\/url]/i',
 '/\[color=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/color]/i',
 '/\[size=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/size]/i'
 );

 $replace = array(
 if ($smileys == true) {
     '<img src="/img/toungue.gif">',
  }
  '<strong>$1</strong>',
  '<u>$1</u>',
  '<i>$1</i>',
  '<img src="$1" alt="$1" />',
  '<a href="$1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="$1">$1</a>',
  '<span style="color:$1">$2</span>',
  '<span style="font-size:$1">$2</span>'
 );

 $str = preg_replace($find, $replace, $str);



return nl2br($str);
}
```

I guess u cant have if clause in array.

And i also tried:

```
function bbcode($str, $smileys = false)
{
 $str = htmlentities($str);

$find = array(
'/\[b](.*?)\[\/b]/i',
    '/\[u](.*?)\[\/u]/i',
'/\[i](.*?)\[\/i]/i',
'/\[img](.*?)\[\/img]/i',
'/\[url](.*?)\[\/url]/i',
'/\[color=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/color]/i',
'/\[size=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/size]/i'
);

$replace = array(
'<strong>$1</strong>',
'<u>$1</u>',
'<i>$1</i>',
'<img src="$1" alt="$1" />',
'<a href="$1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="$1">$1</a>',
'<span style="color:$1">$2</span>',
'<span style="font-size:$1">$2</span>'
);

if ($smileys == true) {

 $find = array(
 ':p'
);

 $replace = array(
 '<img src="/img/toungue.gif">'
);
}

$str = preg_replace($find, $replace, $str);



return nl2br($str);
}
```

Equals to = No ending delimiter ':' found in functions.php on line 68

Answer (score 1):

*I guess u cant have if clause in array.*

Yes you can, but it's called a [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).