# Replace smileys inside [code][/code] tags

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

So I started [a post before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007422/how-to-stop-bbcode-smileys-inside-code-code-tags) but it got closed :( since then I have managed to progress a little realizing I need to somehow grab the content inside the `[code][/code]` tags and do a `str_replace()` on the smiley bbcode text within them, here is what I have so far but its not working

```
if (preg_match_all('~[code](.*?)[\/code]~i', $row['message'], $match)){

 foreach($match[1] AS $key) {
   $find    = array(':)',':(',':P',':D',':O',';)','B)',':confused:',':mad:',':redface:',':rolleyes:',':unsure:');
   $replace = array('&#58;&#41;','&#58;&#40;','&#58;P','&#58;D','&#58;O','&#59;&#41;','B&#41;','&#58;confused&#58;','&#58;mad&#58;','&#58;redface&#58;','&#58;rolleyes&#58;','&#58;unsure&#58;');
}
 $message = str_replace($find, $replace, $key);
  } else {
 $message = $row['message'];
}
```

it just returns no message content at all.

if i change this line:

```
$message = str_replace($find, $replace, $key);
```

to this:

```
$message = str_replace($find, $replace, $row['message']);
```

it sort of works but replaces all smileys inside the whole message rather then just the content inside the `[code][/code]` tags which I assume is being represented by `$key`?! ...any help please its causing my brain to overload!

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234254/php-function-bbcode-make-optional-to-replace-smileys) which is different but very relevant to mine but there was no real answer to it.

Comment: Please post the test data you're using here.  We see a lot of non-working code and it's not all that helpful. But if we can see the test data we can almost always show the right way to handle it.

Comment: as Ray said a sample input would help..

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback()` instead. Consider a recursive regex (tokenization) instead of step-wise replacing. Yes, that's more effort. (No help as all this is boring and the result of you refusing a readymade solution.)

Comment: Sorry not quite sure what you mean, the function I use for bbcode replacement is linked in first post, a message is posted and stored in a DB and called via `$row['message']` if this contains content within `[code][/code]` but also has smiley chars (see first post) I need to stop the bbcode function from replacing the smiley text.

Comment: As mentioned in your previous question [1] I don't think you will come very far (and secure ;)) with regular expression here. Parse the text. Parsing is a process, where you split a text into tokens, build a tree of it (like with nodes of type `BbcodeCodeNode`) and then interprete it. [1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007422/how-to-stop-bbcode-smileys-inside-code-code-tags Also there is a ready to use library for bbcode. Google.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be easier for you to use an existing BBCode parser (eg. [NBBC](http://nbbc.sourceforge.net/)) or at least checking how they did that.  And they did it in a much more intelligent way.  Rather than using regexp, they use a lexer, which splits it into separate tags (shown below).  Then, they just don’t do anything to a [code] tag.  If you still want to stay with your solution, I would, for one, split them out to arrays (`bbcode = explode('[code]', bbcode)` and then the same for [code].  Every second list element should not have other parsing used.  As stated before: there is no purpose in reinventing the wheel, so don’t do that.

This is how their solution works:

```
[b]Hello![/b]
[code]
#/usr/bin/python
import antigravity
[/code]
Python is much more awesome.
```

Becomes eg. an array with the following elements:

1. `[b]Hello![/b]`
2. `[code]…[/code]`
3. `Python is much more awesome.`

And then it applies the formatting it should apply.  Much better and more human.

*not a comment due to length.*